# Progressive filling with Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, delay, debouncing

I want to use an Observable<string[]> for gradually displaying content on component of my Angular apps.

1. On **TypeScript** side I declared this:

```
export class ResultComponent implements OnInit{
 
 message: string = 'my message for user';
 spreadedMessage$: Observable<string> = from(this.message);
 progressiveMessage:string = "";

 ngOnInit() {
    let interval = 1
    this.obsMessage$
      .pipe(
        tap((letter) => {
           delay(35*interval),
           this.progressiveMessage += letter;
          interval++
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
    }
}
```

2. Binding **progressiveMessage** to the template

`<div> {{ progressiveMessage }} </div>`

My full code [listing can be found here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yerop3?file=src/main.ts)

---

I tried a second approach that works well as below but I would like to understand what is wrong with my use of **Observable** to progress.

My alternative solution:

1. Changed `spreadedMessage$: Observable<string> = from(this.message);` to `spreadedMessage: string[] = [...this.message];`
2. Declared this on `OnInit()` method:

```
for (let i: number = 0; i < this.spreadedMessage.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(() => (this.spaceMessager += this.spreadedMessage[i]), 35 * i);    
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing your problem. Ideally in an online code editor such as [Stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example code, `delay()` is not doing anything!  You have included it inside of the `tap` operator, which is not correct.  It needs to be directly within the `.pipe()`.

However, even if you placed it correctly, I think will be tricky to get it to work as you desire because the delay duration is not evaluated for every emission, it's only evaluated once with the initial value of `interval`,

I think something like this *would* work:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.spreadedMessage$.pipe(
      concatMap(letter => of(letter).pipe(delay(35))),
      tap(letter => this.progressiveMessage += letter),
    ).subscribe();
  }
```

Here, we return a new observable inside `concatMap` for each emission, this allows the delay interval to be evaluated for every emitted letter.

---

However, if you are simply trying to emit the characters one at a time at a constant interval, it's probably easier to use the `interval` creator function like this:

```
    interval(35).pipe(
      map(i => this.message[i]),
      take(this.message.length),
      tap(letter => this.progressiveMessage += letter),
    ).subscribe();
```

Since `interval` emits increasing integers starting at `0` we can use that as the index of the character we want to emit.

We use the `take` operator end the stream once the number of emissions has reached the length of the message.

---

To simplify further, we could alleviate the outside variable `progressiveMessage` variable and just emit the portion of the `message` string we are interested in.

```js
  interval(35).pipe(
    map(i => this.message.slice(0, i+1)),
    take(this.message.length),
  ).subscribe();
```

---

And, if you want to simplify even further, you can define your value as an observable and leverage the `async` pipe in the template.  This eliminates subscribing and the use of `ngOnInit`:

```js
  progressiveMessage$ = interval(35).pipe(
    map(i => this.message.slice(0, i+1)),
    take(this.message.length),
  );
```

```html
<p>
  {{ progressiveMessage$ | async }}
</p>
```

Here's a little [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-75986198-ufetdd?file=src%2Fresult%2Fresult.component.html,src%2Fresult%2Fresult.component.ts) example.

Comment: thank you for this optimized and clear response BizzyBob

Answer (score 4):

You are making a very common mistake that many people that are new to RxJS and Observables does; mixing imperative and reactive programming. The idea of the reactive programming is that your observable is the source of truth that the data is displayed from.

Code like

`this.progressiveMessage += letter;`

inside an operator where you assign the new value to another variable is an anti pattern of observables. Instead, use operators to modify and return the new value.

Since you are using Angular, the idea is that you never have to `subscribe` manually in your code, but instead use the `async` pipe in the template.

What you want to do is to create an observable that returns a new value every time the template should be updated.

The `progressiveMessage$` in my code below is an `Observable<string>`, and we assign it a value in the `ngOnInit` function.

```
sentence: string = 'je suis un messsage qui apparait progressivement';
spreadedMessage$: Observable<string> = from(this.sentence);
progressiveMessage$: Observable<string>;

ngOnInit() {
this.progressiveMessage$ = from( // We use the from operator to get a stream from an array
  this.sentence.split('') // Lets split the message up into each character for display purposes
).pipe(
  // here, we first use the concatMap operator to project each source value to a new observable with the of operator
  // we then delay that observable with 250ms, meaning that each observable from the letter array is delayed with 250ms
  concatMap((letter) => of(letter).pipe(delay(250))), 
  // we use the scan operator (much like a regular Array.reduce) to iterate over the values and append the last one to the previous one
  scan((acc, val) => {
    // we return the value here every time a new letter arrives
    return acc + val;
  })
);
}
```

[Here is a working Stackblitz example for you!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srwwbx?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Many thanks Daniel for your responsiveness and the time allowed for your explanation so clear